# Confusing length of variable assigned bytes to str-constructor

Tags: python

```
a = bytes("Ä","utf8")
x = str(a)

print(len(x))
```

It prints `11`

Why? How `2` bytes becomes `11` characters?

Comment: Hint - `print(repr(x), len(x))`

Comment: Did you actually want to print `len(a.decode("utf8"))`, which is how you can convert bytes to strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = bytes("Ä", "utf8")
x = str(a)
print(x)
```

output:

```
b'\xc3\x84'
```

From `b` to the last `'`, there are 11 characters in that string.

This is how Python shows bytes. If you want to retrieve the original text from bytes, which you know is UTF-8 encoded, use `.decode("utf8")`:

```
a = bytes("Ä", "utf8")
y = a.decode("utf8")
print(y)
```

output:

```
Ä
```

If you want to count bytes used, just use `len` on `bytes`:

```
a = bytes("Ä", "utf8")
print(len(a))
```

output

```
2
```

Comment: So the overload of "str()" which takes one argument (type: object) does serialize the object?

Comment: Had the OP done `x=str(a, 'utf-8')` instead it would have worked as expected, yielding one character. This is, imho, convenient but surprising...